# Can't select text with width property in css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm at the moment struggling with some css code.

I have a button that is supposed to change its content after a click (which it does), and enable `user-select: all` after.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .modal-body {
            background-image: 
                /* top, transparent red */
                linear-gradient(
                rgba(1, 104, 31, 0.300), 
                rgba(156, 15, 15, 0.40)
                ),
                /* your image */
                url("https://d1di2lzuh97fh2.cloudfront.net/files/3r/3rz/700/3rzez2.jpg?ph=1be0da70a5");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
        }

        .row {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
        .promo{
            font-size: 1.5em;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1em;
        }
        div.promo{
            margin-top: 2em;
        }
        .subpromo{
            font-size: 1em;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 3em;
        }
        .percent {
            font-size: 4em;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1em;
        }
        button.underline {
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: white;
            font-size: 0.6em;
        }

        button.underline:hover{
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline;

        }

        button.underline:focus{
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        /* Button to get the PROMO code */
 
        .btn-one {
            transition: all 0.5s;
            position: relative;
            cursor:pointer;
            }

        .btn-one span {
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }
        .btn-one::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            border-top-width: 1px;
            border-bottom-width: 1px;
            border-top-style: solid;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
            border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
            transform: scale(0.1, 0.5);
        }
        .btn-one:hover span {
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        } 
        .btn-one:hover::before {
            opacity: 1; 
            transform: scale(1, 1);
        } 
        .btn-one::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
        .btn-one:hover::after {
            opacity: 0; 
            transform: scale(0.1, 1);
        } 

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <!--Modal: modalDiscount-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalDiscount" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content ">
                <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid layer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <p class="text-left">
                                            <h3 style="color: white;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec.</h3>
                                            <p style= "color: white;">Sed interdum ullamcorper arcu, non mollis augue porttitor sit amet. Pellentesque leo elit, interdum vitae porta at, egestas in urna.</p>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <form role="form" class="form">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                        <div class="btn btn-one">
                                                            <span id="promoCode" style="color: white;" >
                                                                 RECEBA O CÓDIGO
                                                            </span> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                                    <button onclick="closeModal()" type="button" class="btn underline">NÃO, OBRIGADO</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 border rounded">
                                        <div class="promo">
                                            <p> RECEBA UM CÓDIGO DE: <span class="percent">10%</span> </p> 
                                            <p> DESCONTO </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="subpromo">
                                            <p>CÓDIGO VÁLIDO PARA UMA UTILIZAÇÃO APENAS NA PRIMEIRA COMPRA. OFERTA VÁLIDA EM ARTIGOS SEM PROMOÇÃO</p> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal: modalDiscount-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $('#modalDiscount').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function closeModal(){
            $('#modalDiscount').modal('hide');
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $('.btn-one').one('click', function(){
            $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#promoCode').text('Stuff to be selected');
                $(this).fadeIn('slow');  
                $(this).css("user-select", "all");
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently it is not working, but I made a few tests, and apparently if I remove `width: 100%` it does work, allowing me to select the text. But I need the `width` property, as it does some animation in the button.

Any suggestions/fix?

Comment: can you show all the css and html? I tried it with the current code and it's working

Comment: @Mouna Yes! Sorry, i though that was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs successfully. After click on the button, when use click on button, the whole button title will select.

Try to run code Snippet.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<Style>
.btn-one::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.5);
}
</Style>

<title>Login Page - Self Demand</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

</head>
<body>
<button id ="promoCode" class="btn-one"> test </button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.btn-one').one('click', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#promoCode').text('Stuff to be selected');
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');  
        $(this).css("user-select", "all");
    });
})

</script>
</html>
```